# Iscroll - Jquery - Get position on a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

The error I'm having is the following:

To the right of my page, I have a list of interesting points (displayed on a map to the left of the page).
Because the list is so long, I am using iScroll 4 (great plugin).

However, what I would like to do is fire an event when the user has scrolled the list, so I can check which items are currently visible to the user. iScroll already has an event set up for that, so I have a function that fires when needed. However, I cannot seem to get the proper coordinates of my list items.

What happens is the following:

1. When the list loads, I get an .offset() value for the first element. offset.top = 35, because my list starts 35px lower than the top edge of the page. This is good.
2. When I scroll the list; say I pull it down for 500px; I would expect the new location to be 35px - 500px = -465px. However, it sill says 35. Scrolling though the list does not affect the elemen'ts coordinates even though it has moved.

How can I get the actual coordinates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Playing with iScroll, I think I found the solution.  the `offset()` function is javascript refering to the #scroller div, which doesn't change.  However internally, iScroll uses its own x and y properties.

So you can refer to the iScroll offset like this

```
var myScroll = new iScroll(...)
alert(myScroll.y)  // -- will return your offset (negative number)
```

Comment: Yeah I firgured that one out yesterday. But you're wrong about offset. .position() gets the coordinates relative to the #scroller div. .offset gets the coordinates relative to the page (not the window, but the entire document). Sice you answered and it was coreect, I'm giving you the tick ;)

Answer (score 1):

add in iscroll.js

```
getScrollY: function () { var that = this; return that.y; },
```